# Количество символов в накопленных элементах

Tags: c++

Извиняюсь сразу же за такой громоздкий код, это я так, чтобы вам было понятнее. Я хочу, чтобы при каждом вводе мной элемента, счетчик засчитал количество символов в элементе и при выводе элементов он под ним же выводил число символов (ВСЕГО) в элементах. Не в одном, а во всех элементах (5, 10, 15 и т.д). Это не чтобы за меня вы решали, просто я с одним элементов справился, а вот с несколькими нет, прошу помочь именно в этом.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

struct element {
    string data;
    element *adress;
};

class List {
  private:
    element * StartAdress, *FinishAdress;

  public:
    List() {
        StartAdress = NULL;
        FinishAdress = NULL;
    } void ElAdd(string a) {
        element *e;
        e = new element;
        e->data = a;
        /*e -> adress = StartAdress;
           StartAdress = e; */
        if (StartAdress == NULL) {
            StartAdress = e;
        } else {
            FinishAdress->adress = e;
        }

        FinishAdress = e;
        FinishAdress->adress = NULL;
    }

    void print() {
        element *e;
        for (e = StartAdress; e != NULL; e = e->adress)
            cout << e->data << " " << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    List L;
    string x;
    cout << "Bufer is Empty! nn";

    cout << "For the Add Elements Press 'A':n";
    {

        char v = getch();
        if (v == 'a') {
            cout << endl;

            cout << "Enter Elements: n";

          start:
            getline(cin, x);

            L.ElAdd(x);
            cout << "--------n";
        }
        cout << "Elements of Your List:nn";
        L.print();
        cout << "--------nn";

        cout << "For the Continue of Adding Press 'P':n";
        cout << "For the Clear Buffer Press 'C':n";
        v = getch();
        if (v == 'p') {
            cout << "Enter the Next Element: n";
            goto start;
        }
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

то что Вы мне посоветовали, выводит ошибки, которых я описал в 7-ом комментарии 1-го ответа. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с ошибками.

Comment: Не вдумываясь в остальной код: Ваш код не соответствует современным концепциям программирования, а значит изначально неверен.  

    goto start;
P.S. тем более метка start внутри `if`, а это вообще ужас что.

Comment: а что вместо него можно добавить туда? ну чтобы тот же эффект был?

А на счет P.S мне нужно чтобы он именно оттуда и начинал, поэтому

Comment: @nav1893 попробуйте самостоятельно переписать без `goto`, если не получится- задайте новый вопрос, и в будущем навсегда забудьте слово `goto`. Это просто маленький совет.

Comment: спасибо! постараюсь. А на счет длины строк ничего не можете добавить?

Comment: @navi1893, у Вас, помнится, ьыл похожий вопрос про добавление/удаление со списком. Вам посоветовали использовать оператор switch внутри while.

IMHO здесь то же самое.

Comment: я вот switch'ом пытался, но код застревает чет там зачем то. Зацикливается, скажем там, но повторно попытаюсь я.

Answer (score 1):

Надо в классе `List` добавить `private` переменную типа int и при добавлении элемента прибавлять значение длинны элемента к этой переменной

```
totalSymbols += a.lenght();
```

а при выводе, также выводить значение переменной `totalSymbols`.

Comment: а почему выдает ошибку: expected `;' before '+=' token, на эту же строку с вашим кодом???

Comment: а переменную в классе List с типом int и именем totalSymbols объявили?

Comment: да, он там же выдает ошибку! =/ Я вот так сделал: 
 
    private:
       element *StartAdress, *FinishAdress;
       int TotalSymbols += x.length();

Вот тут же выводит ошибку! А я x.length() написал, так да? я же 'x' ввожу

Comment: нет, во-первых в классе List добавить private int totalSymbols = 0; потом в функции ElAdd делать totalSymbols += a.lenght();. a потому что в функцию передаётся параметр a, в объявлении void ElAdd(string a)

Comment: инициализировать переменную значит надо в конструкторе, а не при объявлении. Давно на си++ писал, не помню позволяет он при объявлении или нет.

Comment: Нет @navi1893. 

В этом месте надо просто объявить int TotalSymbols. 

В конструкторе обнулить его, аналогично StartAdress и FinishAdress. 

А наращивать в методе ElAdd() TotalSymbols += a.length();

Когда у Вас появится метод, удаляющий элемент списка, не забудьте уменьшить TotalSymbols.

Comment: @CyberCoder при написании в private этой строки, у меня вышло много ошибок на счет этой строки! 1)ISO C++ forbids initialization of member `totalSymbols'  2)making `totalSymbols' static  3)ISO C++ forbids in-class initialization of non-const static member `totalSymbols'  4) In member function `void List::ElAdd(std::string)':  А на эту строку:  totalSymbols += a.lenght();  Следующее:  'struct std::string' has no member named 'lenght'  В чем проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Я не сишник, если честно, пишу утрированно и возможно не правильно. Поправки к ошибкам приму с радостью- повышу свои знания C#.

```
int total=0;
getline(cin, x);
while (x=='a'){
    getline(cin, x);
    L.ElAdd(x);
    total+=x.length();
    cout<<total;
    getline(cin, x); // если введут А то заново
};
```

Comment: В while операция == для сравнения string с char (символом) не определена. Но можно сравнить с "a", поскольку getline для string отбрасывает '\n'

Comment: То есть `'a'` и `"a"` это разные вещи?..

Comment: Точно. 'a' это символ, char, один байт. "a" это строка, массив char, завершается нулевым байтом (в длине строки не учитывается) часто пишут, например, char *str т.е. указатель, адрес. В этом случае строка (ее байты с нулем в конце) находится по адресу, который хранится в переменной str.